# Dockerfile test require directive unable to find the correct module

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-16.04, serverspec

I am trying to write a basic test of an Ubuntu 16.04 docker image.
My testing environment is Ubuntu 16.04 also and I have installed the `ruby-serverspec` package.

```
require "serverspec"
require "docker_image"

describe "Dockerfile" do
  before(:all) do
    image = Docker::Image.build_from_dir('..')

    set :os, family: :debian
    set :backend, :docker
    set :docker_image, image.id
  end

  it "installs the right version of Ubuntu" do
    expect(os_version).to include("Ubuntu 14")
  end

  def os_version
    command("lsb_release -a").stdout
  end
end
```

This is a deliberately failing test for now, as it checks for Ubuntu 14, but it is not even reaching the failure.

```
$ rspec /test/spec/localhost/my_spec.rb    
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- docker_image (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /test/spec/localhost/my_spec.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/runner.rb:106:in `setup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /usr/bin/rspec:4:in `<main>'
```

I am unaware of how to require the `Docker::Image` class module correctly.
The search path is still a black art to me. How can I get this test to fail as expected?

Comment: You are not actually using serverspec at all in that code. You should probably remove it. However, you are using specinfra for the docker backend.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's right approach, Serverspec should only verify your environment, which should be configured by some kind of configuration management (Chef, Puppet, etc..).

However, looks like you are including wrong gem/file. You should replace second line with `require "docker-api"`. `Docker::Image` is a class from [`docker-api` gem](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api/blob/master/lib/docker/image.rb). Gem has to be installed before running tests.